# A word for 'not listening and thinking of a response'

Tags: single-word-requests

Whats the word used for, people who don't listen to what people say and think of only what they want to say?

I think its definition also says those who think of themselves higher than others.

Comment: "Preoccupied," even if not the right word might lead you to a synonym.

Comment: This reminds me of something Fran Leibowitz wrote: "Listening is not the opposite of speaking.  Waiting is."

Comment: Listening to respond, not to understand. Possible paraphrase of the question but I do not have an answer in a single word. I think the definition of egocentric is on target.

Answer (score 3):

Not a single word, but this is similar to the phrase "Talking past each other"

> Talking past each other is an English phrase meaning two or more people talking about different subjects, while they believe that they are talking about the same thing.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_past_each_other)

If the interlocutor is asking a question, it can be thought of as a case of "question dodging"

> Question dodging is the intentional avoidance of answering a question.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_dodging)

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure if there's one specific word to encompass it (perhaps inattentive?), inactive and selective listening are the broader communication terms (as opposed to active and reflective listening - which are great skills to have).

> **Selective Listening**: "You hear only what you want to hear. You hear
>   some of the message and immediately begin to formulate your reply or
>   second guess the speaker without waiting for the speaker to finish."
>
> **Inactive Listening**: "You hear the words, but your mind is wandering
>   and no communication is taking place."

So the person doing this may be a *selective listener*.

Answer (score 0):

A 'snob' is generally a person who looks down upon people who are below him. But I don't think that was the word you were looking for.

Here, you can say that the person was patronizing and turned a deaf ear to what other had to say.

patronize

verb
1.
treat with an apparent kindness which betrays a feeling of superiority.

Alternative words: Condescending.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that comes to my mind is "myopic".  It's a word comes from the eye condition called "myopia" meaning near-sighted.  It is sometimes used to describe a person who lives his life as is he had "blinders" or "blinkers" on: a person who sees life selectively.

Such a person might also be described as "egocentric": having little or no regard for interests, beliefs, or attitudes other than one's own; self-centered.

Answer (score 0):

***domineering / self-asserting / self-centred***

All from ODO:

> **[domineer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/domineer?q=domineering)**
> *VERB*
> [NO OBJECT] (*usually as adjective* **domineering**)
>
> Assert one’s will
> over another in an arrogant way:
>
> Cathy had been a martyr to her gruff, domineering husband
>
> **[self-assertion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-assertion?q=self-asserting#self-assertion__4)**
> *NOUN*
> *[MASS NOUN]*
>
> The confident and forceful expression or promotion of oneself, one’s views, or one’s desires:
>
> her self-assertion was born from a confident determination to succeed
>
> the occasion became one of national self-assertion
>
> **[self-centred](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-centred#self-centred__2)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Preoccupied with oneself and one’s affairs: he’s far too self-centred
> to care what you do